# Show that $M\cap\mathbb{N}\neq\emptyset$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $M=\{ax+by\mid x,y\in\mathbb{Z}\}, a,b\in\mathbb{Z}, b\neq 0$.

Show that $M$ contains at least one natural number, that is $M\cap\mathbb{N}\neq\emptyset$.

**My attempt:**

If $(x,y)=(0,n), n\in\mathbb{N}$, then

$bn\in M$.

Is this the right way to go? How to proceed?

Comment: What about $x=0$ and $y=b$?

Comment: @jukka.aalto: Well, it can get you there, but you'll need to proceed by cases with that approach, since it works if $b$ is positive, but not if $b$ is negative. (Can you see why?)

Comment: @CameronBuie No, If $b$ is negative, will this not be true: $b^2\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @jukka.aalto: Absolutely (though $bn$ will not be)!

Comment: @CameronBuie So you're talking about when $(x,y)=(0,n)$ (my approach) and not when $(x,y)=(0,b)$ (Michael Hoppes approach)?

Comment: @jukka.aalto: Yes. Your approach must be by cases. Michael Hoppe's is more straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Michael Hoppe, one can pick $(x,y)=(0,b)$ and see that $M$ contains at least one natural number.